# After faulty git push, 'everything up to date' prevents pushing anything

Tags: git

I'm deploying a Laravel app by means of a post-receive hook on the production server. However, I made a typo in the hook when writing out the path of the work-tree. After pushing, I received the following message:

```
remote: hooks/post-receive: 1: hooks/post-receive: !#/bin/sh: not found
remote: fatal: Not a git repository: '/path/with/typosgoeshere'
```

It stated that it had counted, compressed, and written 169 objects (delta 26) which is right for the project in question. However, because of the error, nothing was actually pushed to the server. Furthermore, when I attempt to do `git push production master` now, it simply returns 'everything-up-to-date.' I tried `git reset --hard` as I saw suggested elsewhere, but that didn't do anything.

Answer (score 5):

It's not possible to re-`push` content that already exists in a Git remote, nor can you force a branch to "update" itself when it doesn't change. Your best bet is to push a new commit to trigger the hook:

```
git commit --allow-empty -m "Redeploy"
git push production master
```